# Keeping java subprocess alive in background

Tags: java, process, subprocess, builder

I have a class with a method that creates a process using process builder. I then have 2 other methods that use global variables to write commands and collect responses from the process.

I want to start the process from another class and then be able to write commands using the other methods as I wish from this original class. However, I can't see a way to keep the sub-process alive. If I use `.waitFor()` then I'm unable to run any other commands as it hangs (waiting for the sub-process to exit). But if I just leave the create method to complete, once I've returned to the original class and call the input method the process has been killed. Is there any way to keep the process alive but asleep? Allowing the program to continue but being able to call back to it.

Comment: multi-threading should solve this. Launch the subprocess from one `Thread` and use another one to send commands to the subprocess

Comment: Why not return a reference to the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your subprocess in new Thread. If you are not familiar with concept of multi-threading and concurrent processing check out this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Further if you want your subprocess to live after your main program has finished, you need to set that thread to be **daemon** thread.

To learn more about Thread and daemon threads checkout Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Okay, so I have placed the processbuilder in the run() method for the second thread. I can then start the thread but then as soon as it finishes the run method the process is killed so I can call the other methods in the class to input and output?

Comment: OK - additional clarification with subprocess I was referring to processing in general not heavy-weight (operating system process) that you would create using ProcessBuilder. There is a difference between running your 'processing' in multiple threads (aka lightweight thread) and running your processes in different os threads. Nothing is stopping you to create and kick of new Process (using PB) from new (child) thread. this allows you to you continue execution of you main thread. While child thread (deamon) will continue to run until Process that it started finishes

Comment: The problem you are having is that subprocess that you ran has finished by the time you are trying to 'talk' to it. In your situation you are doing inter-process communication and what Java allows (from perspective of using ProcessBuilder (PB)) is to communicate via Input/Output Streams - those you need to setup before you start the process. If your main process (maybe in another thread) is sending something to Input of your subprocess, subprocess needs to be written so it **waits** on input.

Comment: Start from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Okay, so I implemented a while to loop to wait for input but still after a couple of seconds pb just kills the systemprocess, is there any way to stop this? Or can you explain why it shuts it off

Comment: why don't you post your full code (update your post) and we can see

Comment: I realised I'd been a bit of an idiot and had left \C prompt in the command. Changed it to \K and now it stays alive.